# Can I have both FAQ and How-to markups on the same page?

Tags: schema.org, markup

I'm new to structured data.

I am trying to write an article about applying a certain type of license and want to use both the FAQ and How-To markups to better describe the FAQ section and the how-to sections on the same web page.

I was wondering if using these two markups on the same page might result in receiving some sort of penalties.

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters! There are no penalties for using, mark-up. Do what is right for your users. Google does not own the web. Maybe soon, but not yet. [insert grin] Cheers!!

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the comment! Really appreciate it! I will proceed with the initial plan then. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Most likely no penalty. And structured data penalties only mean you do not get rich results for it.

Rich results for these types are incompatible, so you will get one or the other.

Best case scenario is that Google will pick the right rich result for the right search. i.e. a how to like search will show the how to rich result. One related to a question will show the FAQ rich result.

It would be nice to know how things go if you do this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I'll let you know what how things go if ever I try it out!